# How to apply Xamarin Platform-Specific EnableTranslucentNavigationBar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm testing out Xamarin Forms's [new Platform-Specifics features](https://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-xamarin-forms-2-3-3-native-view-declaration-and-platform-specifics/) (in 2.3.3). In particular, the `EnableTranslucentNavigationBar`.

I have a RootPage object that is a `MasterDetail`. The Detail is a `NavigationPage`. Here's my relevant App() ctor code:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Note: RootPage is MasterDetail, Detail is NavigationPage
    var rootPage = new RootPage(); 
    (rootPage.Detail as NavigationPage).On<iOS>().EnableTranslucentNavigationBar();
    MainPage = rootPage;
}
```

This however is not applying the translucent navigation bar effect on the NavigationPage. It is still a solid color (default white) and the content doesn't scroll up

Is there a specific place/time I need to apply this?

Side Note: While working on this, I also noticed a weird ambiguity between two different NavigationPage objects. One in `Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage` and one in `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.NavigationPage`. I eventually got the method to use the former, but it made me think that I might need to cast it first...

**UPDATE:**

Xamarin reports this should be fixed in 2.3.4-pre1

Comment: An additional side-question: Does the translucency have a "frosted glass" effect and does it extend to the edges of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has confirmed this is an issue in Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3 and are investigating. [Go here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49104) to see the Bugzilla report.

I will update this post once I hear back from them regarding a fix or workaround.

UPDATE
Should be fixed in 2.3.4-pre1